# Play song at specific time position from a playlist

Tags: javascript, jquery, audio, jplayer

I am using [jPlayer](http://jplayer.org) plugin.

In example there are 13 songs in playlist. I want to set a start time (currentTime) for each song like : 1st song starts from 2 sec, 2nd song start from 3 sec and 5th song start from 4 sec.

Here is an example [jsFiddle](http://bit.ly/1LCQWZZ).

In this example I added `var tag = $('.audio-tag audio')[0];` to find current playing song globally but it is out of jPlayer plugin.

How to get current audio `tag` & `number` to set currentTime for each song of jPlayer playlist?

Comment: What do you mean with "currentTime"? How many times the song was played?

Comment: currentTime mean number of seconds(start from). I want to set number of seconds(start from) for each song. @alexP

Comment: Isn't the start time 0 for every song? Sorry, I don't understand the logic behind this.

Comment: In example there are 13 songs in playlist. i want to set a start time (currentTime) for each song like : 1st song start from 2s, 2nd song start from 3s and 5th song start from 4s. do you understand now? @alexP

Comment: So it's a single audio file with multiple tracks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

```
var $jp = $('#jquery_jplayer_1');
$jp.on($.jPlayer.event.setmedia,  function(e){
   console.log("Current track", e.jPlayer.status.media);
   console.log("Currentr track index", myPlayer.current);

   // For first track (0) - 2 sec, second track (1) - 3 sec, etc.
   var time = myPlayer.current + 2;

   // Jump to desired time
   setTimeout(function(){ 
       $jp.jPlayer( "play", time); 
   }, 100);
});
```

**NOTES**

Call `setTimeoout` is needed because according to the [manual](http://jplayer.org/latest/developer-guide/#jPlayer-play)

> If issued immediately after a `setMedia` command, with the `time` parameter, and when the browser is using the HTML5 solution, this command will initially fail and an internal timeout is setup to retry the command every 100ms until it succeeds.

**DEMO**

See [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qegp2t54/3/) for code and demonstration.